# Any faster way to find the number of "lucky triples"?

Tags: algorithm

I am working on a code challenge problem -- "find lucky triples". "Lucky triple" is defined as "In a list `lst`, for any combination of triple like `(lst[i], lst[j], lst[k]) where i < j < k`, where `lst[i] divides lst[j]` and `lst[j] divides lst[k]`.

My task is to find the number of lucky triples in a given list. The brute force way is to use three loops but it takes too much time to solve the problem. I wrote this one and the system respond "time exceed". The problems looks silly and easy but the array is unsorted so general methods like binary search do not work. I am stun in the problem for one day and hope someone can give me a hint. I am seeking a way to solve the problem faster, at least the time complexity should be lower than O(N^3).

Comment: " Is there any way faster to find the total number of lucky triples?" Presumably the answer is "yes" if this has been assigned as homework. What have you tried?

Comment: @JohnColeman I have written the brute force one. I have not figured out any other method so I am seeking for help. Why do you guys downvote this? Please let me know what I should improve.

Comment: The way the question was phrased made it seem a bit too much like a mere statement of a homework problem with no evidence of effort on the student's part to solve it. Many of these types of question are posted each day and they tend to be heavily downvoted. Your question might have been mistaken for such a question. You would have gotten a much better response if you had said that you had implemented a brute-force solution and wanted some hints about finding a more efficient solution. If you edit your question slightly, I'll gladly change my downvote to an upvote.

Comment: @JohnColeman, Hi, John, I have modified the description. Hope it works fine. Any idea about the problem is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: If a%b = 0 and b%c = 0, what about a%c?

Comment: @greybeard you are right, but we need find the triple

Comment: @greybeard Thank you for your remainder. I just modify it back ;)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A simple dynamic programming-like algorithm will do this in quadratic time and linear space. You just have to maintain a counter `c[i]` for each item in the list, that represents the number of previous integers that divides `L[i]`.

Then, as you go through the list and test each integer `L[k]` with all previous item `L[j]`, if `L[j]` divides `L[k]`, you just add `c[j]` (which could be 0) to your global counter of triples, because that also implies that there exist exactly `c[j]` items `L[i]` such that `L[i]` divides `L[j]` and `i < j`.

```
int c[] = {0}
int nbTriples = 0
for k=0 to n-1
  for j=0 to k-1
    if (L[k] % L[j] == 0)
      c[k]++
      nbTriples += c[j]
return nbTriples
```

There may be some better algorithm that uses fancy discrete maths to do it faster, but if O(n^2) is ok, this will do just fine.

In regard to your comment:

- *Why DP?* We have something that can clearly be modeled as having a **left to right order** (DP orange flag), and it feels like **reusing previously computed values** could be interesting, because the brute force algorithm does the exact same computations a lot of times.
- *How to get from that to a solution?* Run a simple example (hint: it should better be by treating input from left to right). At step `i`, compute what you can compute from this particular point (ignoring everything on the right of i), and try to pinpoint what you compute over and over again for different `i's`: this is what you want to cache. Here, when you see a potential triple at step `k` (`L[k] % L[j] == 0`), you have to consider what happens on `L[j]`: "*does it have some divisors on its left too? Each of these would give us a new triple. Let's see... But wait! We already computed that on step `j`! Let's cache this value!*" And this is when you jump on your seat.

Comment: Very concise solution. I tried to use dynamic programming to solve it but do not find the rules. Could you share your thinking process? Like how to you come up with the idea use dp and how do you define the transition formula.

Comment: Please tell me the answer for the following array according to your algorithm: `a = [3, 6, 5, 30, 18]`

Comment: There are 2 valid triples above, `[3,6,18], [3,6,30]`. Your code gives a different answer...

Comment: @User_Targaryen I'm sorry, I didn't verify, it may very well be the case. But I can't see how it fails: it will return 2 on your sample, won't it? Anyway, the important thing is that DP is applicable and very simple here.

Comment: No, it doesn't return 2.. check again...Even I coded a similar solution like yours, but found the flaw..

Comment: @User_Targaryen Sorry again, I did check and failed to see the problem...

Comment: @PatriceGahide: Please show me the array c[] after complete computation. Your final answer is a summation over all elements of c[], right??

Comment: @User_Targaryen Wrong. The final answer is `nbTriples`. `c[]` is just the cache, a tool to compute `nbTriples` throughout the process.

Comment: @User_Targaryen Well thanks for pointing that the returned value is not as obvious as I thought. I've edited the pseudo-code to make it clear.

Comment: Does this work for non-sorted lists? This seems to work on the assumption of sorting the list beforehand

Comment: @user760900 Yes, it absolutely works on non sorted lists.

Answer (score 8):

Full working solution in python:

```py
c = [0] * len(l)
print c
count = 0

for i in range(0,len(l)):
  j=0
  for j in range(0, i):
    if l[i] % l[j] == 0:
      c[i] = c[i] + 1
      count = count + c[j]
    print j           

print c
print count
```

Comment: With multiplicity.

Answer (score 2):

Read up on the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes), a common technique for finding prime numbers, which could be adapted to find your 'lucky triples'. Essentially, you would need to iterate your list in increasing value order, and for each value, multiply it by an increasing factor until it is larger than the largest list element, and each time one of these multiples equals another value in the list, the multiple is divisible by the base number. If the list is sorted when given to you, then the i < j < k requirement would also be satisfied.

e.g. Given the list `[3, 4, 8, 15, 16, 20, 40]`:

Start at `3`, which has multiples `[6, 9, 12, 15, 18 ... 39]` within the range of the list. Of those multiples, only `15` is contained in the list, so record under `15` that it has a factor `3`.

Proceed to `4`, which has multiples `[8, 12, 16, 20, 24, 28, 32, 36, 40]`. Mark those as having a factor 4.

Continue through the list. When you reach an element that has an existing known factor, then if you find any multiples of that number in the list, then you have a triple. In this case, for `16`, this has a multiple `32` which is in the list. So now you know that `32` is divisible by `16`, which is divisible by `4`. Whereas for `15`, that has no multiples in the list, so there is no value that can form a triplet with `3` and `15`.

Comment: It is good solution but the list is unsorted. DO you have any other idea? When dealing with unsorted array, the  common methods may not work. I try to preprocess the data but I DO NOT WORK

Comment: Sieve of Eratosthenes is a good reference that adds another perspective to the solution. There is lesson and some more code challenges on [Codility](https://app.codility.com/programmers/lessons/11-sieve_of_eratosthenes) which may be useful to others as it been to me.

Answer (score 2):

A `precomputation` step to the problem can help reduce time complexity.

**Precomputation Step**:

For every element(i), iterate the array to find which are the elements(j) such that `lst[j]%lst[i]==0`

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
   for(j=i+1;j<n;j++)
   {
      if(a[j]%a[i] == 0)
         // mark those j's. You decide how to store this data
   }
}
```

This **Precomputation Step** will take `O(n^2)` time.

In the **Ultimate Step**, use the details of the **Precomputation Step**, to help find the triplets..

Comment: It seems this way is the same as the brute force one. After precomputation, I got the eligible numbers of lst[j]. If I use the marked numbers lst[j], the whole process is like splitting three loops to two sections of two loops but the computation number is the same.

Comment: @Anderson: If you have to enumerate all the different lucky triples, then the worst case has to be O(N^3). If you have to only count the number of such lucky triples, then you can find it in O(N^2) time with O(N) space. Do you want me to supply you with the code that only returns the count of such triples??

Comment: @User_Targaryen Good point about the worst case (e.g. 2,4,8,...,2^N) but it seems like if the numbers are random you should be able to get to an average-time complexity which is quadratic. Maybe something involving building up a tree as the list is scanned.

Comment: @User_Targaryen, Thank you for your help, I only need count of triples. Just implement a O((N ^ 2 )* lgN) solution and it still yield to time exceed

Answer (score 0):

Forming a graph - an array of the indices which are multiples ahead of the current index. Then calculating the collective sum of multiples of these indices, referred from the graph. It has a complexity of O(n^2)

For example, for a list {1,2,3,4,5,6} there will be an array of the multiples. The graph will look like
{ 0:[1,2,3,4,5], 1:[3,5], 2: [5], 3:[],4:[], 5:[]}

So, total triplets will be {0->1 ->3/5} and {0->2 ->5} ie., 3

```
package com.welldyne.mx.dao.core;

import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class LuckyTriplets {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] integers = new int[2000];

    for (int i = 1; i < 2001; i++) {

        integers[i - 1] = i;
    }
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    int n = findLuckyTriplets(integers);
    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println((end - start) + " ms");
    System.out.println(n);

  }

  private static int findLuckyTriplets(int[] integers) {

    List<Integer>[] indexMultiples = new LinkedList[integers.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < integers.length; i++) {

        indexMultiples[i] = getMultiples(integers, i);
    }

    int luckyTriplets = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < integers.length - 1; i++) {

        luckyTriplets += getLuckyTripletsFromMultiplesMap(indexMultiples, i);
    }
    return luckyTriplets;
  }

  private static int getLuckyTripletsFromMultiplesMap(List<Integer>[] indexMultiples, int n) {

    int sum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < indexMultiples[n].size(); i++) {

        sum += indexMultiples[(indexMultiples[n].get(i))].size();
    }

    return sum;
  }

  private static List<Integer> getMultiples(int[] integers, int n) {

    List<Integer> multiples = new LinkedList<>();
    for (int i = n + 1; i < integers.length; i++) {

        if (isMultiple(integers[n], integers[i])) {

            multiples.add(i);
        }
    }
    return multiples;
 }

 /*
  * if b is the multiple of a
  */
 private static boolean isMultiple(int a, int b) {

    return b % a == 0;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to share my solution, which passed. Basically, the problem can be condensed to a tree problem. You need to pay attention to the wording of the question, it only treats numbers different on basis of the index not value. so {1,1,1} will have only 1 triple, but {1,1,1,1} will have 4. the constraint is {li,lj,lk} such that the divide and i<j<k

```
def solution(l):
    count = 0
    data = l
    max_element = max(data)
    tree_list = []
    
    for p,element in enumerate(data):
        
        if element == 0:
            tree_list.append([])
        
        else:
            temp = []
            for el in data[p+1:]:
                if el%element == 0:
                    temp.append(el)
            
            tree_list.append(temp)
    
    for p,element_list in enumerate(tree_list):
        data[p] = 0
        temp = data[:]
        for element in element_list:
            pos_element = temp.index(element)
            count += len(tree_list[pos_element])
            temp[pos_element] = 0
        
    return count
```